# Write to a non-existant device using dd

Tags: live-usb, dd

Hello I wanted to write an iso image to an USB stick (which is in /dev/sdd)
but I've made a slight typo, instead of typing:

```
dd if=/path/to/downloaded.iso of=/dev/sdd
```

I typed:

```
dd if=/path/to/downloaded.iso of=/dev/sdd}
```

After that dd told me it wrote arround 1.5 MB, so I checked, and the file "/dev/sdd}" was created. Is this harmful?

PD: I deleted the /dev/sdd} file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No; it is just a regular file on disk.  Had you let it finish, you would simply have had a copy of the iso file named `/dev/sdd}`.  In other words, there is nothing special about the /dev directory so you can create new regular files there all you like.  It is only the dev nodes that the system creates there that are special.

Comment: Thanks...That's what I thought but I wasn't sure