# Copying files to an erroneous or non-existant file path

Tags: filesystem, cd

I was scouring the ether for general information related to Linux files systems generally, and more specifically what happens if I specify a wrong root-sub directory when performing commands. To be exact, I made a mistake of having double slash at the beginning of my path.

`//mnt/.../...` instead of `/mnt/.../...`

I have noticed that I can `cd` into this location, but this seems to mirror the correct directory location.

1. Have I unintentionally created a new directory?
2. Would I need to perform further actions rto resolve?

There is a similar [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/651986/write-to-a-non-existant-device-using-dd) which is answered, but refers more to a typo at the end of the path description, which is similar, but different, as the type is at the end of the path (changing the file name).

Comment: That does indeed. Thanks. Although the information is pretty indepth, and I feel as if I'm just peering into another rabbit-hole, I definetly would accept the answer. If I can accept it with my account's lack of privileges, I will! Cheers again.